# ESP32 dual core multi tasks priority issue

Tags: task, esp32, freertos

task1 : webServerTask,
task2 : guiTask (use mutex)
I assigned task1 to cpu0 and task2 to cpu1 using the xTaskCreatePinnedToCore function in esp32. Then I expected task1 and task2 to run concurrently on each other’s cpu regardless of their respective priorities, isn’t that right?
If I increase the priority of task1 over task2, task2 will not run. If I set the priorities to be the same, both tasks will run. Even if I assign tasks to different CPUs, does the execution of the tasks differ according to their priority? Or is it related to the use of semaphore in task2?

case 1: webServerTask run, guiTask does not work (priority: task1 > task2, task2 with mutex)

```cpp
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(webServerTask, "webServer", 4096, NULL, 2, NULL, 0);
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(guiTask, "gui", 4096 * 2, NULL, 1, NULL, 1);
```

case 2: both webServerTask and guiTask run (priority: task1 = task2, task2 with mutex)

```cpp
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(webServerTask, "webServer", 4096, NULL, 1, NULL, 0);
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(guiTask, "gui", 4096 * 2, NULL, 1, NULL, 1);
```

case 3: both webServerTask and guiTask run (priority: task1 > task2, task2 without mutex)

```cpp
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(webServerTask, "webServer", 4096, NULL, 2, NULL, 0);
xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(guiTask, "gui", 4096 * 2, NULL, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Task1 and Task2 are implemented as below:

```
static void webServerTask(void *pvParameters)
{
  // initialize wifi and the web server
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  // Run the web server loop indefinitely
  while(1)
  {
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client)
    {
      ...
     }
    vTaskDelay(10 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  } 
}


static void guiTask(void *pvParameter)
{
  xGuiSemaphore = xSemaphoreCreateMutex(); 
  ...  // display

  while (1)
  {
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(10));

    if (pdTRUE == xSemaphoreTake(xGuiSemaphore, portMAX_DELAY))
    {
      lv_task_handler();
      xSemaphoreGive(xGuiSemaphore);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you use the semaphore? I would expect this to happen if the task with the higher priority is always holding the semaphore and doing some busy-looping while it owns it.